# Cannot fetch branch from git-svn repo

Tags: git, git-svn

I wanted to create a new branch on the svn server and then create a local branch to track this new branch.

But I think something went wrong during this process because a branch is created on the svn server, but I am not able to fetch it.

```
$git svn branch -m "new-branch-message" new-branch
Copying http://pathtorepo/project/trunk at r28074 to http://pathtorepo/project/branches/new-branch...
Found possible branch point: http://pathtorepo/project/branches/BRANCH-2-2-11-0 => http://pathtorepo/project/tags/VER-2_2_11-1, 27365
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/tags/VER-2_2_11-1) 243dea0687bd6721621ab4f7287dec7e121489e8
Following parent with do_switch
Invalid filesystem path syntax: Cannot replace a directory from within at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 5097

$cat .git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://pathtorepo
    fetch = project/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = project/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = project/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*

$git svn --version
git-svn version 1.7.1 (svn 1.6.11)
```

Any thoughts on what that 'Invalid filesystem path syntax' error means? Did I set up the git repo correctly?

Comment: You need to cd (change directory) to the place where you want the new branch. Currently it's trying to write where the svn command is located.

Comment: Can you explain? Do I need to create a directory for a branch? If so; where? Why is it writing where the svn command is located?

Comment: Typically you would create a directory somewhere of your choosing named for example `repo` then you would `cd` into there and run your commmand `git svn branch` ...

Comment: The [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) don't say anything about creating a directory. I also think the problem is actually with fetching the svn repo because `git svn fetch` gives the same (Invalid filesystem path syntax) error.

Comment: Was a solution found for this?

Comment: @AndyF I did not, I solved it by checking out the full repo again; it wasn't that large in my case.